# How to get two bootstrap cards side by side to act responsive using a media query?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Media Query for bootstrap 4, unresponsive. I have two cards side by side in a section. When I get down to `576px` I want to be able to display the cards side by side.

I've tried setting the parent containers to `float: none` and `float: left`. Also tried incorporating `display: block` on the Query.

```
<section id="recipeList">
    <div class="recipeName"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card image-container">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="./assets/images/Dish.svg" 
                    alt="places restaurants png">
                <div class="card-body ingredients" id="foodImage">
                    <p class="card-text"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card ingredients-card">
                <img class="card-img-top" 
                    src="./assets/images/Contents.svg" alt="places restaurants png">
                <div class="card-body overflow-auto">
                    <h2 class="card-title"></h2>
                    <p class="card-text overflow-auto" id="facts"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I would love for the two bootstrap cards to be responsive rather than just squeezing downwards

Comment: Use col-6 class instead of col-sm-6

Comment: still doesn't work, the list just keeps on going down..

Comment: See it works :https://jsfiddle.net/8z0ah46e/

Comment: I resized that box and it does the same thing my html does. it stays the same length through out but that stretches the text out. I don't want that. I'm looking for it to float on top of one another.